# Unable to translate "Signup" displayed during site maintenance

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, sign-up, maintenance

I can't find the string to translate "Signup" displayed during site maintenance:

> [image: signup]

Moreover, the tail part of sentence is present as a separate string:

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/6317

This is not good practice for localization purposes. Much better to use a full sentence available for translation, i.e. "Signup is currently unavailable".

Instead we got an incorrect translation, e.g. with "Login" word:

> [image: login incorrect translation]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've replaced the messages to use full sentences. That will allow for more flexible translations.
Since we just introduced https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=is%20not%20available, they are not translated yet.

Hope that helps!

Comment: To find these strings, just search for `is not available` in Traducir: [Russian](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=is%20not%20available), [Japanese](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=is%20not%20available), [Spanish](https://es.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=is%20not%20available), [Portuguese](https://pt.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=is%20not%20available)